# Unable to get values in NodeJs Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make post request but unable to get values in Postman; it's sending `undefined`. I am using Express version `4.17.1`. Below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const dburl = process.env.URL;

router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.post('/register',(req,res) => {

   var data = {

      name:req.body.name,
      email:req.body.email,
   };

     res.send(data);

   });

module.exports = router;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share error details.

Comment: Earlier i was using `router.use(bodyParser.json())` and `router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))` but here bodyParser was shwoing deprecated then I changed it to `express` in place of `bodyParser` in above statements.Now its not getting values.

Comment: cross check the format you sending through postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet works, tested with express 4.17.1 on node 12.19.0. The issue must be from elsewhere.

Possible issues are:

- The parser for `router` could have been overridden by the parser for `app` (assuming you're calling `app.use(router)` somewhere).
  Can you move this to app level?

```
router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```